# Having issue launching Eclipse on Feodra 24

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora

When I was on Fedora 23, I was using Eclipse Neon to work on my school projects and it worked fine. However, I recently updated to Fedora 24, and now, for some reasons, I can't launch it anymore. Whenever I try to launch eclipse from the terminal, I bump into an error message, telling me that it can't find a java virtual machine in a specific folder (you can see the error message on the screenshot I've attached). [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf77R.jpg)
I looked up the mentioned folder, and noticed that some files were already installed in here. Besides, when I try to install java using the dnf command, to check if anything is missing from my installed version, the terminal tells me that the package is already installed.

Would someone have any idea how to fix this issue? I've been trying to use some solutions I found on the net, but none did work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paths on the screenshot do not match.
You are checking files inside `...fc24.x86_64` while eclipse is looking for `...fc23.x86_64`.
Update your JRE location in `eclipse.ini`. You can probably just remove lines:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/.../jre/bin
```

and eclipse will pick your system default JRE.